# variable scope of __init__

Tags: python

I just wonder, why variable defined by `__init__` is not accessible from class? Should its executed during instantiation, so that its accessible from outside?

```
>>> class a:
...     data = {}
... 
>>> a.data
{}
>>> class a:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.data = {}
... 
>>> a.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class a has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: What is the colour of the concept of balls in general?

Comment: To reduce confusion, you should always give the classes uppercase (CamelCase) names as of [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Here you see that `A` is only the class itself; `__init__`is called during `a = A()`, after which `a.data` actually exists, as opposite to `A.data`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Variables defined in `__init__` are *instance* variables, by definition they can't be accessed from a class scope. That's why this works:

```
a().data # data is a member of an instance of class `a`
```

... Whereas this won't work:

```
a.data   # data is not a member of the `a` class
```

Notice that `__init__` (the *initializer*) is run when you create a new instance of `a` by calling `a()`, from that point on all the variables defined in `__init__` are bound to that particular instance of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a blueprint for objects. The `__init__` method runs on each object to set up its contents. You made an `__init__` that says "every `a` object shall start out with a `data` attribute".

Now you want to access `data` through the `a` class itself.

*Which object*'s `data` do you expect to receive? And why? The `data` is not part of the class itself. The `a` class itself is different from any given `a` object, in the same way that a ball is different from the *concept of balls*. A ball can be blue. The concept of balls cannot.